# Cygwin: How to pass parameter for a windows program?

Tags: cygwin, windows-scripting

I have a small problem with cygwin and passing parameters to a windows program.

My knowledge about windows shells and so on is pretty small. A friend of mine wrote a program for windows to do some calculations. To start the program you just need a console and you have to type something like `program.exe param1 param2 param3` everything runs without any problems.

What I need now is to run for different parameters (a lot of different parameters). To do it so, I thought about scripting something and to call 1000times the program by the script. That's why I'm using cygwin because I don't have any windows scripting experience, but some experiences with Linux and bash. My problem is right now I don't know how to pass the parameters for the call.

I tried to pass an array to the command, but this didn't worked out. What I tried:

```
args=("param1" "param2" "param3")
./program.exe $args
```

**EDIT**

It seems to work if I do the following (as an example):

```
args="param1 param2 param3"
eval "./program.exe $args"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
args="param1 param2 param3"
./program.exe $args
```

For unix-style arguments this works:

```
args="-l -t"
ls $args
```

For Windows style arguments double the slashes:

```
taskkill //PID 15804
```

Comment: I tried also. This works properly on `ls` and other bash commands (I guess), but not with this program.

Comment: Tried `args=(param1 param2 param3)
./program.exe ${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]}` ?

Comment: If launching a windows command you need to double-up on your slashes, eg `tasklist //fo csv` instead of `tasklist /fo csv`